# HTML text triggers PHP

Tags: php, html

I am pretty new to PHP, but I have a fair idea about how it works.
My question is this: is it possible to have something like %username%, in HTML, and when PHP recognises this text, it will output a username?
Ie: turn the %username% to the actual username?

How would this be done, or how does it work?

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: You mean something equivalent to the ASP.NET controls?

Comment: Google for "php template engine". Multiple options available out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually done through **Template Engines** like **Smarty** for example. See the next definition from [smarty.net](http://smarty.net)

> **[What's a template engine and why should I use one?](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#basics-1)**
>
> Smarty is a template engine for PHP. More specifically, it facilitates
>   a managable way to separate application logic and content from its
>   presentation. This is best described in a situation where the
>   application programmer and the template designer play different roles,
>   or in most cases are not the same person. For example, let's say you
>   are creating a web page that is displaying a newspaper article. The
>   article headline, tagline, author and body are content elements, they
>   contain no information about how they will be presented. They are
>   passed into Smarty by the application, then the template designer
>   edits the templates and uses a combination of HTML tags and template
>   tags to format the presentation of these elements (HTML tables,
>   background colors, font sizes, style sheets, etc.) One day the
>   programmer needs to change the way the article content is retrieved (a
>   change in application logic.) This change does not affect the template
>   designer, the content will still arrive in the template exactly the
>   same. Likewise, if the template designer wants to completely redesign
>   the templates, this requires no changes to the application logic.
>   Therefore, the programmer can make changes to the application logic
>   without the need to restructure templates, and the template designer
>   can make changes to templates without breaking application logic.

and there are many other template engines other than smarty, just google for it.

Comment: Than you for your help! This sounds like what I was looking for, although, does using something like Smarty slow down your web page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
<?
$username = "However you get your username";
// other serverside logic
?>

<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <? echo $username; ?>
    <BODY>
</HTML>
```

It won't get any shorter.

It's just an echo-statement, I don't think I need to explain that.

Comment: what about `I have <?=$foo?> foo.`

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say without using PHP tags at all. You have simple HTML - %username% - no PHP involved, but when included onto the PHP page, this text will be changed to a users username. I have seen this done, but am not sure how to do this.

Comment: @11684 no - this works in php too (short_open_tags enabled..)

Comment: @zuc0001 Perhaps that wasn't PHP but another preprocessor? Never seen it.

Comment: Ah ok. would you have any idea how to do his in PHP ?

Comment: @Philipp Is `short_open_tags` a module?

Comment: `short_open_tags` is an option in the `php.ini` file - see http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: No. I do not mean <? ?> . You do not have ANY PHP involved in the %username% - this is only HTML. No <? Around it. But when I <? Include the page that %username% is on, this HTML will be turned into the users username.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is something like this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/...

Comment: Well, an HTML parser is a bit of an overkill perhaps. What do you think of regexes? Have one page called `page.php` or something similar, give it a GET variable with which file it should display, and before echoing it, it does `preg_match()` with `%.+%`, and replaces it with the corresponding variable... @zuc0001

Answer (score 0):

There are more options to achive this - you can use the php.ini options [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to use `<?=$varname ?>` syntax. You can also use the php.ini option `asp_tags` to use `<%=$var %>` for var output.

But i think the best option is to use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). Using a template engine you can strictly seperate design and code logic.